# Got an Error when creating "MVC Controller with Views using Entity Framework" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

Error Detail:

There was an error running the selected code generator: ‘Method ‘get_QueryProvider’ in type ‘Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalDatabaseFacadeDependencies’ from assembly ‘Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60’ does not have an implementation.’
[Click Here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4rqz.png)

Creating MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework [Clear Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlC0L.png). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

Probably because you have a nuget package which has a higher version.
I had the same problem. I had EF.Core 6.0.11 and EF 7.0.0. Just try to have all your EF nuget packages on the same version.